# Free overlay extensions with Prototype API?

Tags: overlay, prototypejs

Anyone know of free overlay extensions for the Prototype API?

[Lightview](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/) is great, but it costs money.

The goal is to create attractive, simple overlays quickly for our client at http://www.panabee.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked through [Scripteka][1]?

[1]: http://www.scripteka.com Scripteka